# Magento 2.1.7 - Create a new product tax class

Tags: magento-2.1, tax-class

[image]How to create a new product tax class in magento 2.1.7 and create two different tax rates for same region.

I am unable to find "Add new tax class" button under additional settings when creating new tax rule.

Comment: Can you take a screen shot?

Comment: I have added screenshot. I cannot find "Add new tax class" button for product and customer tax class under additional settings.

Answer (score 0):

To add new tax class please go to Tax Rules >  Add New Tax Rule. Here you can find the button for adding class.

[image]

Comment: I am checking it on the same screen but i could not found it. Do we have some settings to enable it?

Comment: Also, when i inspect element i could found the text "Add new tax class" and script from which it is coming but it is not showing on the screen.

Comment: Unable to resolve dependency: TaxRateEditableMultiselect getting this error in console

Comment: Can you please recompile the magento setup and deploy static content? And please do check configuration for your country setup and merchant country

Comment: Unable to resolve dependency: EditableMultiselect                         
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Dec/2017:17:32:00 +0530] "GET /pub/static/version1514286735/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery/editableMultiselect/js/jquery.multiselect.js HTTP/1.1" 304 in apache access.log

Comment: Please copy the file from <<magento root>>/lib/web/jquery/editableMultiselect/js/jquery.multiselect.js to  <<magento root>>/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_U‌​S/jquery/editableMul‌​tiselect/js/jquery.multiselect.js for temporary and please reset your permission for magento installation as per the guide. It might possible that due to incorrect permission files are not generated properly. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

Comment: Also if files are there and generated properly then change the setting Stores > Configuration > Developer > Static Files Settings > Sign Static Files to No and check  .htaccess file in /pub/static/ folder.

Comment: In my case, setting Merge javascript to "No" in store->configuration->advanced->developer->javascript setting resolved the issue. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, setting store->configuration->advanced->developer->javascript setting->Merge javascript files to "No" in  resolved the issue. Thankyou